# VMWare Fusion OS X 10.13.5 GUID partition

Tags: disk-utility, high-sierra, partition, vmware

I'm using VMWare Fusion 8.5.10, and OS X 10.13.5 as client.

In VMWare I shutdown the vm first, then I increased the size of the virtual hard disk. Now in OS X I use Disk Utility to increase the size of the existing partition by deleting Free space first, then resize the existing partition to use up all the deleted space.

But Disk Utility says:

Operation failed...
An internal error has occurred and the disk for one of the specified operations could not be found.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `diskutil` helped me fix the problem.

`diskutil list` This will list the partitions

`diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 0` This will resize the disk0s2 partition to fill

I found the solution on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/unRAID/comments/8vg4ja/resizing_a_vm_disk_high_sierra/).

Answer (score 0):

Restart the system in single user mode.

To restart your system in single user mode, restart your Mac and as soon as it turns off and is about to start, press and hold CMD + S buttons.

You should see a command prompt logged in as root.

Now, run the following command:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

if your drive was OK, the screen will say “The volume (name of your hard drive) appears to be OK”. If any repair was made, you’ll see the prompt, “FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED”. Then, you’ll see the root# prompt again.

Then try to restart the system and try deleting the space. It should work. If not, you'll have to use the `diskutil` command to override this thing and get it to work.

In case the solutions I've provided here is not working for you, please do this:

Reboot your mac in Recovery mode(While rebooting hold CMD + R), launch terminal and run `diskutil list` and update your question with the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using High Sierra and APFS. Try this.

Below command to find the list of Drives.

```
diskutil list
```

run this to retrieve the the free space.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Now your unused free space will be added to your existing hard disk as a single partition.

Comment: Unfortunately my partition is not AFPS....so this didn’t work.